# ruamel.yaml - how to output null instead of !!null '' when default_flow_style=None

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

Using ruamel.yaml in Python, if I dump with the SafeRepresenter or RoundTripRepresenter and default_flow_style the default, null is represented as expected.

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
yaml = YAML(typ='rt')
yaml.dump({'key1': None, 'url': 'https://lala/', 'key2': None}, sys.stdout)

key1:
url: https://lala/
key2:
```

However, if I change the default_flow_style to None, the representer for null seems to be ignored and instead null is represented as !!null '' eg.

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
yaml = YAML(typ='rt')
yaml.default_flow_style = None
yaml.dump({'key1': None, 'url': 'https://lala/', 'key2': None}, sys.stdout)


key: {key1: !!null '', url: https://lala/, key2: !!null ''}
```

Setting the representer for null explicitly makes no difference e.g.

```
SafeRepresenter.add_representer(type(None), RoundTripRepresenter.represent_none)
```

I tried the above, but output for null when using the `SafeRepresenter` instead of the `RoundTripRepresenter` was still `!!null ''` when using `default_flow_style=None`.

How do I output `null` instead of `!!null ''` when using `default_flow_style=None` directly from `ruamel.yaml` rather than doing postprocessing on its output (e.g. a find replace)?

Comment: Can you include in your question a minimal example that reproduces this behavior? If I use `ruamel.yaml` to dump a dictionary with a `None` value, it shows up as a simple `null` in the output, regardless of the setting of `default_flow_style`.

Comment: @larsks I've updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possible solutions.

The easiest solution is to use `typ='safe'` instead of `typ='rt'`. This is what I generally do , but if you're relying on `ruamel.yaml`'s ability to preserve things like comments, this isn't an option.

You can create a representer for `None` values like this:

```
def represent_none(self, data):
    return self.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:null', 'null')
```

Which will print out your `None` values as desired:

```
>>> import sys
>>> from ruamel.yaml import YAML
>>> yaml = YAML(typ='rt')
>>> yaml.default_flow_style = None
>>>
>>> def represent_none(self, data):
...     return self.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:null', 'null')
...
>>> yaml.representer.add_representer(type(None), represent_none)
>>> yaml.dump({'key1': None, 'url': 'https://lala/', 'key2': None}, sys.stdout)
{key1: null, url: https://lala/, key2: null}
```

Answer (score 2):

The round-trip dumper tries to dump `None` as the empty string, which will not
parse back correctly (and at then end of a flow style sequence would be
undistinguishable from a sequence with a trailing comma).

The tagged output was the result of the emitter detecting this could not be parsed back, but it is ugly and this
is fixed in `ruamel.yaml` 0.16.13, by emitting `null` instead of `!!null ''`, This does not affect block style
emitting of `None`:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
yaml = YAML(typ='rt')
yaml.default_flow_style = None
yaml.dump({'key1': None, 'url': 'https://lala/', 'key2': None}, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
{key1: null, url: https://lala/, key2: null}
```

You can get the old behaviour setting `yaml.emitter.alt_null = None`. You can
set that to any value, although choosing one of the other [Null
Language-Indepenent Type](https://yaml.org/type/null.html) values (`Null`,
`NULL`, `~`) makes the most sense:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
map = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.emitter.alt_null = '~'
b = map(key1=None, url='https://lala/', key2=None)
b.fa.set_flow_style()
yaml.dump(dict(a=None, b=b), sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
a:
b: {key1: ~, url: https://lala/, key2: ~}
```